# What is the T and Z in timedate getting returned by MongoMapper?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

When I return a JSON format of created_at & updated_at from MongoMapper, this is an example of what I see

`"updated_at\":\"2012-04-25T16:25:05Z\"`

What is the T (time?) and Z at the end?

```
 irb(main):009:0> Story.last.created_at
  DEBUG - MONGODB (0ms) prototype_development['stories'].find({}).limit(-1)
=> 2012-04-25 16:24:26 UTC
irb(main):010:0> Story.last.created_at.to_s
  DEBUG - MONGODB (0ms) prototype_development['stories'].find({}).limit(-1)
=> "2012-04-25 16:24:26 UTC"
irb(main):011:0> JSON.parse(Story.last.to_json)['created_at']
  DEBUG - MONGODB (0ms) prototype_development['stories'].find({}).limit(-1)
=> "2012-04-25T16:24:26Z"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a standardized time format - [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Hit this in `irb`:

```
> require 'time' #=> true
> Time.now.utc.iso8601 #=> "2012-05-11T01:28:51Z"
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):

> The UTC time zone is sometimes denoted by the letter Z—a reference to
>   the equivalent nautical time zone (GMT), which has been denoted by a Z
>   since about 1950.
>   The letter also refers to the "zone description" of zero hours, which
>   has been used since 1920 (see time zone history). Since the NATO
>   phonetic alphabet and amateur radio word for Z is "Zulu", UTC is
>   sometimes known as Zulu time. This is especially true in aviation,
>   where Zulu is the universal standard. This ensures all pilots
>   regardless of location are using the same 24-hour clock, thus avoiding
>   confusion when flying between time zones.See list of military
>   time zones for letters used in addition to Z in qualifying time zones
>   other than Greenwich.